# handle subdomains through .htaccess file in php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm building an web portal in which each user will have a Vanity URL's defined during the registration, so when they try to access the Vanity URL's I need the sub-domain name & URL should remain same. Let's discuss in detail.

Let's say I have my main domain "www.mymaindomain.com". User "ABC" registered with my portal & vanity (SUB domain ) URL's for "ABC" user is "abc.mymaindomain.com". When he hits the URL "abc.mymaindomain.com" it should show him home page with some additional info related to his profile. But I have to get the subdomain name "abc" from URL for processing his profile information on the display page. Please do help me,

Thanks in advance..
Srinivasu.

Comment: Thats a one-liner: `array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));`

Answer (score -1):

This is RTM, have a look at Virtual User Hosts example [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST}                 ^www\.[^.]+\.host\.com$
RewriteRule   ^(.+)                        %{HTTP_HOST}$1          [C]
RewriteRule   ^www\.([^.]+)\.host\.com(.*) /home/$1$2
```

Comment: I want the URL to be remained same Alexander Balabin.. Only need to get the sub domain name, when user hits the URL ("abc.mymaindomain.com") I want to fetch the abc as a query string so that I can fetch abc user contact info for display on home page..

Comment: `^www\.([^.]+)\.host\.com(.*) /$2?user=$1` if your original url does not have a query string. It would be a bit more complicated but I think doable if it did.